# Hide object with jquery on document ready() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, dom, hide, document-ready

I want to hide an id, when loading the window with jquery .hide().

Somehow I cant get it to work. I looked at other similar questions, but didn't find the answer. All help appriciated.

Here's my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#remove_header").hide();
  });
```

I'm a newbie, so don't be afraid to spell it with big letters.

Answer (score 0):

Use class selector instead of id selector as you need to hide based on class name:

```
 $(".remove_header").hide();
```

Comment: I made a mistake, I meant id insted of class. The "remove_header" is an ID and not a class. The code is put in the <head> of my html file. But somehow, it doesn't work. I have also included a link for jquery-latest.

Comment: No, nothing. You can see the site [here](http://beernominate.me/createUser.html). It's the yellow bar I want to remove. I need it in some pages, so instead of deleting it, I just want to hide it.

Comment: @TommyOtzen: `remove_header` is not id. its class. use above code.

Comment: I have inserted the above code, but without succes?

Comment: @TommyOtzen: i just executed the code `$(".remove_header").hide();` in console. in it hides the desired element. have you inseted in document ready event??

Comment: '$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".remove_header").hide();
});'
This is the full code in my <head> tag. But I can't get the element to hide()?

Comment: @TommyOtzen: how are you adding the element on page.

Answer (score 0):

Use "." for class and "#" is used for Id's

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".remove_header").hide();
});
```